# How to solve this error....Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    data = pd.read_excel('F:/Desktop/Downloads/Funds_Holding_12_11_2017.xls')
    M_Cap = pd.read_excel('F:/Desktop/Share_4_Feb_2018.xlsx','CAP(R2)_New')
    Shariah = pd.read_excel('F:/Shariah_List.xlsx')
    Data = data[['Ticker','SecurityName','FundCode','FundName','TotalValueFund','LiquidityNative']]
    Shariah_Data = Shariah[['Ticker','Compliance Status: DEC 2017']]
    Filter_Fund = Data['FundCode'].isin ([14, 16, 17, 24, 25, 49])
    Fund = Data[Filter_Fund]
    total_assets = np.sum(Fund['TotalValueFund'])+np.sum(Fund['LiquidityNative'])
    weights = Fund['TotalValueFund']/total_assets

# 10% Breach Calculation
    Fund['10% Breach'] = weights > 0.1
    Fund['Weightage'] = round(weights*100,2)
    out_1 = Fund[['Ticker','SecurityName','FundCode','FundName','Weightage','10%     Breach','TotalValueFund']]
    Cap_Data = M_Cap[['Ticker','% of Total  Free','S&P Saudi Arabia','Free Float Mrk.','Riyad Income BM']]
    newdata = out_1.merge(Cap_Data, on = 'Ticker', how ='inner')

#Market Cap Calculation
    if Fund == 14:
        newdata['Mkt_Cap'] = newdata['Weightage'] < newdata['% of Total  Free']
    elif Fund == 16:
        newdata['Mkt_Cap_S&P'] = newdata['Weightage'] < newdata['S&P Saudi Arabia']
    CAP = Shariah_Data.merge(Cap_Data_16, on = 'Ticker', how = 'inner')
    newdata = out_1.merge(Cap_Data, on = 'Ticker', how ='inner')
    elif Fund == 17:
        newdata['Mkt_Cap_RI'] = newdata['Weightage'] < newdata['Riyad Income BM']
    elif Fund == 24:
        newdata['Mkt_Cap_Emaar'] = newdata['Weightage'] < newdata['Al Emaar BM %']
    elif Fund == 25:
        newdata['Mkt_Cap_BI'] = newdata['Weightage'] < newdata['SBIF (S&P Sharia)']
    elif Fund == 49:
        newdata['Mkt_Cap_Mid'] = newdata['Weightage'] < newdata['S&P SA Shariah']
    else:
        print("No Data Available")

# 5% Holding Calculation
    Holding = newdata['TotalValueFund'] / (newdata['Free Float Mrk.']*1000000)
    newdata['Holding Weight'] = Holding*100
    newdata['5% Holdings'] = Holding > 0.05
    newdata['% of Total Free'] = newdata['% of Total  Free']*100
    Final_Result = newdata[['Ticker','SecurityName','FundCode','FundName','Weightage','% of Total Free','10% Breach','Mkt_Cap','Mkt_Cap_S&P','Mkt_Cap_RI','Mkt_Cap_Emaar','Mkt_Cap_BI','Mkt_Cap_Mid','5% Holdings','Compliance Status: DEC 2017']]
    Final_Result.to_excel('F:/Monitoring.xlsx')
```

After running the above, I got the error:

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Please advise how can I solve this issue.

Comment: Hi! Please include input data and fix indent in code below #Market Cap Calculation. And it will be useful to show complete error stack.

Comment: Where do the `14`, `16`, `17`, `24`, `25`, `49` values come from? Are they a specific company's `FundCode`?

Comment: This is internal defined codes for the funds.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what you are trying to achieve with your code. However, the reason why you see an error is clear:

```
data = pd.read_excel('F:/Desktop/Downloads/Funds_Holding_12_11_2017.xls')
# So 'data' is a pandas dataframe

Data = data[['Ticker','SecurityName','FundCode','FundName','TotalValueFund','LiquidityNative']]
# 'Data' is a dataframe as it's a slice of 'data'

Fund = Data[Filter_Fund]
# 'Fund' id a dataframe as it's a slice of 'Data'

weights = Fund['TotalValueFund']/total_assets
# 'weights' id a dataframe as it's a simple function of 'Fund'

Fund['10% Breach'] = weights > 0.1
# 'Fund' is a dataframe as it's a simple function of 'weights'

if Fund == 14:
# You are comparing 'Fund' to an integer.
```

Pandas gets confused and thinks you are trying to check the truthness of your dataframe via `if Fund`, a non-permitted method as it is ambiguous.

Comment: I want to compare market cap with our fund with respect to their benchmark. So what should I do in this case

Comment: @ArfeenZia. Solve one problem at a time. I've explained above why the error occurs, but I can't / shouldn't rewrite your entire script for you. For that, you can hire some professional expertise. Amend your code in line with my response according to what you want. Check the result. Come back with another question if you're really stuck and have tried everything you can.

Comment: Thanks mate for your response. I have already done this calculation separately, I just wanted to try it with the above approach. Anyways, thanks for your time and efforts.

Comment: Thanks mate for your response. I have already done this calculation separately, I just wanted to try it with the above approach. Anyways, thanks for your time and efforts.